# Adding circles to every state in my d3 US map visualization

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-science, visualize

I am looking to visualize an extra dimension by using circles that show the amount of page views per state. This is what I have in mind: [image]

This is what I have so far:

https://github.com/akassem97/usMapViz/blob/master/finalWork/visualization1.html

I included the whole repo due to you all needing the dataset to view the visualization. Here is how it looks now: [image]

I cant seem to find a way to add to the svg with the topojson I am using.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I tried to use                                                                              
                `svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "bubble")
                .selectAll("circle")
                        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
                    .enter().append("circle")`                                                                                However the us states geojson/topojson I am using does not have toposon defined. I can not find any resources that allow me to do this with what I have.